# Any more\anymore\any longer\no longer\ no more

Tags: adverbs, some-vs-any

I wanted to say a sentence below but I made whole 5 variants of how it could be said. Do they really mean the same or the differ somehow?

> 1) From what shelf will people not be taking milk any longer?
>
> 2) From what shelf will people not be taking milk any more?
>
> 3) From what shelf will people not be taking milk anymore?
>
> 4) From what shelf will people be taking milk no longer?
>
> 5) From what shelf will people be taking milk no more?

Answer (score 1):

2 is incorrect; "any more" is not an adverbial phrase.

4 is awkward, and 5 is very awkward verging on ungrammatical. Putting negations at the end of sentences like 4 and 5 do is archaic and confusing (you're waiting until the very end of the sentence to tell the listener that you're saying the *opposite* of what you've been saying so far). I would prefer "From which shelf will people no longer be taking milk?" to any of the options presented.

Answer (score 0):

My first comment is that the begining should be:

> From **which** shelf...

---

Second comment: regardless of correctness or word order, the sentence is weird, asking a specific detail which will happen NOT.

---

Other than that, if I must choose "the best" sentence, I choose sentence 1:

> 1) From **which** shelf will people not be taking milk any longer?

---

Note: using "what" instead of "which" might mean, depending on the context, that the object either never existed, or it disappeared:

> The milk is on the shelf.
>
> **What** shelf?!

Answer (score -2):

They all mean the same thing, although not all of them are grammatical.

Comment: Which ones aren't?

Comment: I'm not a grammatical expert, so I can't necessarily furnish explicit justification. That said, #2, "any more" is awkward; it may yet be correct, #4 and #5 are not in grammatical order. So #4 could be "From what shelf will people no longer be taking milk?" and #5, maybe "From what shelf will people be taking no more milk?" That one is quite awkward. You don't want that negative clause hanging out there after the subject "milk." I think.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.